# I deployed my react app following every step in the docs but when I click on my deployed link the screen is blank. When I run it locally it works fine

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

https://github.com/GeronimoCostaPeuser/my-personal-web-portfolio theres the code.

After tring multiple times and failing I changed "private:" true to "private:" false but that still did not work. I would appreciate some help as I have tried many things.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to React.

For Routing components in a switch inside of your App, you'll want to do things the "React-way" and use the React Router. So instead of doing this:

```js
let Component;

switch(window.location.pathname) {
  case "/":
    Component = Home;
    break;
  case "/projects":
    Component = Projects;
    break;
  case "/blog":
    Component = Blog;
    break;
  case "/certificates":
    Component = Certificates;
    break;
  case "/contactme":
    Component = Contact;
    break;
}

return <Component />;
```

Try doing this:

First, create **routes.js**

```js
import { Route, Routes as RouteSwitch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <RouteSwitch>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
      <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
      <Route path="/certificates" element={<Certificates />} />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </RouteSwitch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Then inside **App.js**, change this from:

```js
<div className="box2">
  <Routes />
</div>
```

To:

```js
import Routes from './Routes';
```

I hope that helps you!